# Accessing current controller instance (`this`) in events

Tags: angularjs, typescript

We are using `TypeScript` with `angularjs 1.5`. We have a situation where we need to trigger an event to load data from the parent component. The problem we are facing is that when the event is triggered, `this` is referring to the `window` object not the controller in which it is present. How to get the current instance in the event?

Because it is `TypeScript` any method or property can be accessed though `this` only. And I need the controller instance because there are few initialization done in the constructor which I need to access.

**Example implementation**

```
namespace doc.common {
     @Component({
          selector: name
     })
     export class myComponent {
            @bind.oneWay()
            public id:number;

            public service:myService;
            /*ngInject*/
            constructor(private serviceRef:myService){
                 this.service = serviceRef;
            }

            public $onChange():void {
                  //*this* is referred to window object, not controller instance
            }
     }
}
```

**Usage**

```
<my-component id='id'></my-component>
```

Comment: Would be  useful to see where this code lives within the controller/directive, so that it's easier to diagnose the issue.

Comment: Code is in controller, no directive here.

Comment: It would be useful to see the controller code as this isn't an issue I've ever encountered with typescript, there are occasions I have to create a `self` variable, but that's only for special circumstances, typescript handles most of those scenarios out the box when it compiles your typescript

Comment: I have updated the sample code. Main code is identical.